# Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals in $R$. Is the set $K= \{ ab \ | \ a\in I, b\in J \}$ an ideal in R?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I've just assumed that this is false, since the problem statements says to compare it to a previous problem where $\{ a+b \ | \ a\in I, b\in J \}$ is ideal.

However, by trial and error I can't find two ideals where this doesn't hold.

Is this false, and if so what's the counterexample? I haven't found one thus far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider (x,y) and (z,w) in Z[x,y,z,w].  Then your set isn't closed under addition: it contains xz and yw but not xz+yw.

Comment: this works if we take $(x,y)$ twice and consider $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Or $I=J=\langle 2,X\rangle$ and consider $4+X^2$.